# How to control when elements in the web page to load?

Tags: javascript, html

This is my situation:
I have a web page which need login, the html looks like this:

```
<head>
    <script src="login_control.js"></script>
</head>
<body>  
    <div id="login"></div>
    <div id="main">  
        many things here(images, etc)
    </div>  
    <script></script>
    <script></script>
    <script></script>
    ...
</body>
```

when the page is loaded, the `login_control.js` is executed, if the user hasn't logged in, the 
`#login` div will be displayed. and the user can't see `div#main`.
Now the problem is that even though the user can't see `div#main`, the contents in it(images, etc) will still be loaded which makes it feel the page is slow...

So I want to know is it possible to do this:
first show the login div, if the user log in successfully, start load the div#main. what's the simplest way to do this?

Comment: What platform is powering the site? (ASP.NET, PHP, other?)

Comment: Once the user is authenticated then you can hide login div and show main div.This is possible.But If you provide us some code then we will able to know what to do?

Comment: @Kiran my problem is not show main div, but not load it until the user login successfully

Comment: Why not just redirect the user to another page on successful login?... Do you *need* this to be a single page app?

Comment: why not put a flag indicator and invoke the function to load it based on the flag value ? something like 0 and 1

Comment: @DemianBrecht If I redirect it to another page, then I have to check if the user is logged in in that page too...because the user may enter the url of that page in browser directly.

Comment: @wong2: That's why you implement authentication strategies

Answer (score 0):

You could start with no `src` on the `<img>`, and then dynamically set it after the user has logged in. Use [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) (XMLHttpRequest) to perform the user login, then if it is successful, set the image src's and set the other div to visible.

Comment: Unless I'm way off base, when your browser parses an `<img src="...">` tag, it fires off a GET request to load the image. But I don't see how that is a problem, I was just addressing your concern.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you could use AJAX to load in the *members-only* content after the user completes their sign in. With jQuery, assuming that you have a server-side means to handle the request URL and return the protected content, after logging in make an AJAX call which resembles something like this:

```
$('#main').load('path/to/protected/content');
```